# ConTeXt: Combination of overstrike and underbar

Tags: context, underline

**Problem**

I currently work on an edition in which I want to render passages that have been marked as 'done' by the source's author (e.g. todo lists). Some of the crossed out items are underlined, and I want to serialize that, too.

Depict these phenomena separately isn't a problem in ConTeXt 1.01., e.g.

```
\starttext

\underbar{Some underlined text.}

\overstrike{Some text that's crossed out.}

\stoptext
```

Combining the two of them, however, doesn't work:

```
\starttext

\underbar{Some underlined \overstrike{crossed out} text.}

\overstrike{Some crossed out text with an \underbar{underlined} word.}

\stoptext
```

---

**Question**

How can I achieve a text that's both underlined AND crossed out?

Comment: The bars work via LuaTeX's node attributes.  In principle stacking could be implemented but it currently isn't.  Perhaps ask on the mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a combination of textbackground and overstrike:

```
\definetextbackground[underline]
  [location=text, voffset=-2pt,alternative=1,background=,frame=off]

\starttext

\startunderline Some underlined \overstrike{crossed out} text.\stopunderline

\stoptext
```

Comment: This works fine for me. I only had to adjust the framecolor which seems to be blue by default for some reason.